# list all the files/directories created by a specific user

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems, directory

Under a folder, there are files created by multiple users. How can I list all the files/directories created by a specific user, using `ls` or something else?

Comment: You can only show ownership, not creation.

Answer (score 0):

As of now it is not possible with 'ls' command but you don't need to worry 'find' is your friend. Suppose my folder is -> /root/sam and I am looking for file owned by shubham, so following command would do the task-

find /root/sam -user shubham

In case you want specific files, say .php files, then following command can be used-

find /root/sam -user shubham "*.php"

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you can only find files that are owned by a certain user. Who created a file is not stored on Unix/Linux systems in general. The following command will give you your file listing.

```
find /path/to/directory -user USERNAME
```

So to find all files from user pete in the home directory of user john use the following command

```
find /home/john -user pete
```

You need to have the right permissions to search /home/john. When you are not logged in as root the command should be preceded by 'sudo'

```
sudo find /home/john -user pete
```